# Post a file to an ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am new to ApiControllers and testing on sending a file from the client to the api and saving it from here. The code below does work and the file is "copied" from the client to the server, but the response message though is "204 No Content" - Should I beware of anything here?

The ApiController code is this:

```
    [HttpPost]      
    [Route("api/UploadFile")]     
    public async Task UploadFile()
    {
        string fileName = "myfilename.txt";
        Stream requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();        

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\myDropFolder\" + fileName))
        {
            await requestStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }         
    }
```

And the call to the client looks like this, testing from a console application:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1741/api/UploadFile/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\myDropFolder\tester.txt");
            request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Send the file as body request. 
                requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", response.ProtocolVersion, (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
                Console.ReadLine();            

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API's default response status code for POST is 204 and for GET is 200 ([Action Results in Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)). Unless you return `IHttpActionResult` and then explicitly return 200:

```
[HttpPost]      
[Route("api/UploadFile")]     
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    string fileName = "myfilename.txt";
    Stream requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();        

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\myDropFolder\" + fileName))
    {
        await requestStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return Ok(); 
}
```